# ArangoDB - Exception in JsonTextReader.ParseValue() when inserting Large document to Remote Server

Tags: c#, nosql, json.net, .net-core, arangodb

I have two instances of ArangoDB running, one on a remote/cloud server and one on a local server. Both instances are accessible and I can insert/query data on both instances.

I have a document that contains an array 56,000+ doubles and when I try to insert this document to the remote server, I get a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException. When I insert the same document to the local instance, the insert succeeds. The error text is:

*'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'*

Can anyone shed some light into what is going on where?

I am using ArangoDB 3.2.6 the and [ArangoDB .Net Client](http://www.arangoclient.net/)

Ping Times: Local:2ms - Remote:56ms

My test code is:

```
int size = 56000;
TestObj toAdd = new TestObj() { values = new List<double>(size) };
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    toAdd.values.Add(_rnd.NextDouble());
}

ArangoDatabase.ChangeSetting(s => {
    s.Database = "MyDB";
    s.Url = "192.1.1.123:8529";
    s.Credential = new NetworkCredential("MyUID", "MyPwd");
});

using (IArangoDatabase db = ArangoDatabase.CreateWithSetting()){
    db.Collection("TestCollection").Insert(toAdd);
}
```

Comment: *'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'* usually indicates that XML is being encountered where JSON was expected.

Comment: Try seeing what the value is before you JSON.parse it, that will help explain the data it's trying to send through to you.

Comment: The payload is an json array inside of curly brackets. {values:[.1234,.5678]}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue lies with the configuration of the [NGINX Reverse Proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/). The client_max_body_size setting was set too low for the JSON documents that were deing load to the server. Once the body size was increased it started working.

Info on the NGINX configuration can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/814767/413-request-entity-too-large-in-nginx-with-client-max-body-size-set).